# Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop Migration From 120GB SSD To RAID1 (software) 1TB SSD Not Booting

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 20.04, ssd, raid

I initially installed `Ubuntu Studio 20.04` onto a 120GB SSD.  I'm wondering if it is possible to migrate this to RAID1 (software) with (2) 1TB SSD drives.

What's confusing me is how `Ubuntu Studio 20.04` installed:

```
sdc         8:32   0 111.8G  0 disk  
├─sdc1      8:33   0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
└─sdc2      8:34   0 111.3G  0 part  /
```

I didn't specifically designate a `/boot/efi` partition during the installation sequence.

I created (2) RAIDs:

```
- 2GB fat32
- 929GB ext4
```

I wanted to make the fat32 partition larger than it would ever require to avoid re-partitioning the drive in the future.

To copy the files onto the RAID partitions I used:

```
rsync -avP --numeric-ids --delete-during {120GB partition} {equivalent RAID1 partition}
```

Additionally I edited `/etc/fstab`

```
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=a461ff1b-8d74-4e24-84e7-fe17e2097f23 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=06A9-23FB  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

However this won't boot.  I am not sure if it can be salvaged.  Was there a different way I was suppose to copy the boot partition?

This is the results of lsblk

```
NAME      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda         8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk  
├─sda1      8:1    0     2G  0 part  
│ └─md127   9:127  0     2G  0 raid1 
└─sda2      8:2    0 929.5G  0 part  
  └─md126   9:126  0 929.4G  0 raid1 
sdb         8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk  
├─sdb1      8:17   0     2G  0 part  
│ └─md127   9:127  0     2G  0 raid1 
└─sdb2      8:18   0 929.5G  0 part  
  └─md126   9:126  0 929.4G  0 raid1 
sdc         8:32   0 111.8G  0 disk  
├─sdc1      8:33   0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
└─sdc2      8:34   0 111.3G  0 part  /
```

I want to set this up so Ubuntu Studio 20.04 will boot from both partitions --- so if 1 SSD dies I can still boot the computer and then replace the SSD.

Answer (score 0):

After much research and help from the folks on the *Freenode* #Ubuntu IRC channel I have an answer.  I ended up re-installing due to all the research and failed attempts.  I've shared my process below.  For those who will use this to migrate to RAID use `rsync -avP --numeric-ids --delete-during /path/from/ /path/to/` for cloning your installed operating system and data (documents, videos, photos, etc.)

I've treated this as many single board computers requiring a microsd card to boot.  I setup the `/boot/efi` partition on a mSATA with a USB adapter I'll Velcro to my computer case.

To make this work I booted the live media and accessed terminal ( `CTRL ALT T` ) used `cfdisk` to create the Linux RAID partitions on each SSD drives for the RAID

`sudo cfdisk /dev/sdLETTER`

**"Select Tabel Type"**: `gpt`

**[New]**

**Partition size:** `###G`

**[Type]** Find `Linux RAID`

**[Write]** "Are you sure you want to write the partition table to disk?" `yes`

**[Quit]**

Then eject, unmount or otherwise power off each SSD and reconnect them.  Note what `/dev/sdLETTER` were assigned using `lsblk`

Next `sudo apt install mdadm` and create the RAID1

`mdadm --create /dev/md/rootfs /dev/sdLETTER1 /dev/sdLETTER1 --level=1 --raid-devices=2`

To monitor the creation of the RAID use: `cat /proc/mdstat`

When complete format the RAID using `mkfs.ext4 -m0 /dev/md/rootfs`

While the RAID is being created create create the `/boot/efi` partition:

Mount the device you will use the `/boot/efi` partition.  I used a mSATA with USB adapter.

Use `lsblk` to identify the assigned `/dev/sdLETTER`.

Create the partition using `cfdisk` steps above.

As the live media for installing Ubuntu 20.04 don't allow formatting using terminal do so with `mkfs.vfat`

Once the RAID has been created use the Ubuntu 20.04 live media installation command to install selecting `/dev/md127` (or the equivalent `/dev/` mount assigned).  Select the `/boot/efi` partition.  Proceed with the installation.

The final step of the installation where `grub` boot is created will fail.  I created this manually using:

```
sudo mount /dev/md127 /mnt
for i in /dev /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -R $i /mnt$i; done
sudo chroot /mnt
apt install mdadm
mdadm --examine /dev/sda1
grub-install /dev/sdLETTER
update-grub
```

My grub-install syntax was more complex:

```
sudo grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi && sudo update-grub
```

Any time new Kernels are installed you will need to edit /etc/fstab to ensure the UUID= matches your RAID and not /dev/sda1.  To fix this mistake:

First confirm the UUID of your RAID parition and /dev/sda1 parition:

```
blkid
```

To display the incorrect UUID assigned:

```
fsck -Af -M
```

Then boot using live media.  Access terminal to install and activate RAID:

```
sudo su -
apt install mdadm
mdadm --assemble /dev/md127 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1
```

The RAID partition should auto mount.  To get the location of the audio mount use:

```
df -h
```

- You will be looking for something like:

  /dev/md127      916G   82G  789G  10% /media/ubuntu-studio/f3c747fb-63d8-455d-8815-6097e1f35d58

If not:

```
mount /dev/md127 /mnt
```

Finally correct the UUID to match your RAID for "/":

```
nano /etc/fstab
```

My entry is:

```
UUID=f3c747fb-63d8-455d-8815-6097e1f35d58 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
```